# Message: Element is disabled and so may not be used for actions error using Selenium on pythonanywhere.com

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, pythonanywhere

I've been working on an automation script with selenium, after developing it locally I was able to make it consistently work on my local browser, however, I would like to set up the file to run on pythonanywhere.com. So I uploaded the code and ran it from there. However, when I run the code I come with an error `Message: Element is disabled and so may not be used for actions`. The element must be correct and interactable with since it worked perfectly locally on my firefox browser, it may be because of version differences in the firefox but I don't think so. I've seen answers for this on Stack but they say that the element is wrong, which shouldn't (but may) apply in my case. I am able to successfully grab the title from the website.

I won't be able to share the code due to the sensitivity of the process, but I can share that's it's a google form and the full error message, any help will be gratefully appreciated.

Thank you

```
Message: Element is disabled and so may not be used for actions
Stacktrace:
    at fxdriver.preconditions.enabled (file:///tmp/tmpi99ptn1x/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:10098)
    at DelayedCommand.checkPreconditions_ (file:///tmp/tmpi99ptn1x/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:126
44)
    at DelayedCommand.executeInternal_/h (file:///tmp/tmpi99ptn1x/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:1266
1)
    at DelayedCommand.executeInternal_ (file:///tmp/tmpi99ptn1x/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12666)
    at DelayedCommand.execute/< (file:///tmp/tmpi99ptn1x/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12608)
```

Answer (score 2):

This error message...

```
Element is disabled and so may not be used for actions
```

...implies that the element with which you are trying to interact is **disabled** and hence cannot be used for actions.

---

### Deep Dive

The relevant HTML and your code trials would have helped us to construct a cannonical answer. However, as you mentioned you were *able to make it consistently work on my local browser* but doesn't *pythonanywhere.com* at this junction it is worth to mention that [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) tends to mock the *User Actions* and some among them are:

- Sending Text : `sendKeys("LiamHarries")`
- Special Keyboard Characters : `sendKeys(Keys.ENTER)` and `sendKeys(Keys.RETURN)`
- Mouse Hover : `moveToElement(element).perform()`
- Click : `click()`

All these *User Actions* are independent of the underlying [os](/questions/tagged/os) and *Hardware* configuration. Hence if they run the same application they will behave the same.

> You can find a detailed discussion in [Chrome & Firefox on Windows vs Linux (selenium)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47939389/chrome-firefox-on-windows-vs-linux-selenium/47939721#47939721)

---

### This error

This issue have been discussed earlier in the thread [Selenium webdriver :org.openqa.selenium.InvalidElementStateException: Element is disabled and so may not be used for actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20772696/selenium-webdriver-org-openqa-selenium-invalidelementstateexception-element-is) where it was pretty much apparent that OP was trying to probe if the element `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='gs_htif0']"))` was **enabled**.

Definitely, the [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) based on the value of `id` attribute **`gs_htif0`** wasn't a static one and hence it is bound to change periodically and may be available/unavailable in indigenous systems.

### Solution

In these cases the solution is to construct the [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890) based on static values of attributes.

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [InvalidElementStateException invalid element state: Element must be user-editable in order to clear it" error while sending text with Selenium Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59572475/invalidelementstateexception-invalid-element-state-element-must-be-user-editabl/59575234#59575234)
- [Invalid element state: Element must be user-editable in order to clear it error trying to click and insert a date on a dropdown-toggle using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58881440/invalid-element-state-element-must-be-user-editable-in-order-to-clear-it-error/58997476#58997476)
- [Selenium : How to solve org.openqa.selenium.InvalidElementStateException: invalid element state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49902198/selenium-how-to-solve-org-openqa-selenium-invalidelementstateexception-invali/49920377#49920377)
- [InvalidElementStateException when attempting to clear text through Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50528377/invalidelementstateexception-when-attempting-to-clear-text-through-selenium/50529031#50529031)

Comment: Thanks so much for replying, I've sent a message to you on Facebook detailing the source code, I would really appreciate any help you could give

Comment: @SalmanB I have provided the most canonical answer considering the information provided within the question.

Comment: Thanks so much for your time but would you mind taking a look at the message I sent you on Facebook, I can't say you answered it because I'm still not sure what to do, I've provided my entire code to you as a file on there, would greatly appreciate any help